# Find the best regex to match title of a citation reference

Tags: java, regex

I have this string `[1]T. Vu, V. Nguyen, T. Nguyen, T. Thieu, V. Pham, G. David, T. Ngo, and T. Le. Hollow gold nanostructures prepared by galvanic replacement reaction: synthesis and optical properties. DOI:https://doi.org/10.15625/0866-708X/53/6/5782` which represent a citation of a paper. I want to write a regex that match only the title of this string. The result is expected to be like so `Hollow gold nanostructures prepared by galvanic replacement reaction: synthesis and optical properties.`

I have tried this regex `(?<=. ).*?(?=[dD][oO][iI]:)` and `(?<=\\.\\s)\\s*(.+?)\\s*(?=[dD][oO][iI]:)` but it only give me this which I don't know why it not match the smallest posible `Vu, V. Nguyen, T. Nguyen, T. Thieu, V. Pham, G. David, T. Ngo, and T. Le. Hollow gold nanostructures prepared by galvanic replacement reaction: synthesis and optical properties.`

How to fix this?

Comment: try this: https://regex101.com/r/Utw3Hb/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because, the dot `(.)` in your regex is a wildcard that matches any character, including commas and spaces

so to fix it check this out :

```
(?<=\\.\\s)[^\\.]+(?=\\.\\sDOI)
```

- `(?<=\\.\\s)`: to ensure it's the beginning of the title (positive lookbehind to match a dot followed by a space)
- `[^\\.]+`: it's matching one or more characters that are not a dot,so this will exclude the author names
- `(?=\\.\\sDOI)`: to ensure it's the end of the title, positive lookahead to matching a dot followed by a space and "DOI" ()

to testing my regex :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "[1]T. Vu, V. Nguyen, T. Nguyen, T. Thieu, V. Pham, G. David, T. Ngo, and T. Le. Hollow gold nanostructures prepared by galvanic replacement reaction: synthesis and optical properties. DOI:https://doi.org/10.15625/0866-708X/53/6/5782";

        String regex = "(?<=\\.\\s)[^\\.]+(?=\\.\\sDOI)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            String title = matcher.group(0);
            System.out.println(title);
        }
    }
}
```

good luck !

Answer (score 0):

A better idea would be to use a regex to extract the DOI and use the DOI to *look up* the publication's title and other metadata using (for example) the CrossRef service's API:

- https://www.crossref.org/documentation/retrieve-metadata/rest-api/

The problem with trying to extract a title from the citation text itself is that citations are provided in all sorts of format, depending on the tools that are used to format them, the requirements of the journal and so on.  That makes extraction complicated ... and difficult to do reliably with regexes.

---

On the other hand, **that** DOI (10.15625/0866-708X/53/6/5782) does not resolve to anything and CrossRef doesn't know about the paper when I search for it by title.  It appears to be a genuine paper because I can find it using a Google search.  However, it looks like "Vietnam Journal of Science and Technology" is not properly registering the DOIs for the papers that they publish!!

Tsk, tsk, tsk.